# How to read a File which contains keywords in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

I have a Question ?
I have a File Which contains one keyword on each line (5000),
I'm developing a Scraper Using Puppeteer in Nodes Which will go to a website which has a Search Bar and in that Search bar I want to search Using the Keywords from that File, So Someone Please Guide me How to accomplish this ? am I Using the right tools ? I would be grateful .

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// yourVariable is the text data.
if(yourVariable.contains("What you are looking for.")){
// the code
}
```

If that is what you mean.
Otherwise, if you mean going to each 5000 lines in the text file, you can use nthline in an async function by running:

```
npm i nthline --save
```

in your console, then:

```
   ;(async () => {
  const nthline = require('nthline'),
    filePath = '/path/to/100-million-rows-file',
    rowIndex = 42
 
  console.log(await nthline(rowIndex, filePath))
})()
```

Or if you want to check if the line contains data:

```
;(async () => {
  const nthline = require('nthline'),
    filePath = '/path/to/100-million-rows-file',
    rowIndex = 42
 
  console.log(await nthline(rowIndex, filePath).contains("Data"))
})()
```